# Why is this not printing the final output of sum?

Tags: c++, arrays, array-sum

Given an array of N integers. My task is to print the sum of all of the integers.

Input:

First line of input file contains a single integer T which denotes the number of test cases. For each test case, there will be two lines. First line contains N which denotes number of elements in an array, and second line contains N space seperated integers.

Output:

Corresponding to each test case, print the sum of array in a new line.

Constraints:

1 <= T <= 100

1 <= N <= 1000

0 <= Arr[i] <= 200

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, no_of_elem_array;
    int arr[50], sum[50];

    cin >> n;

    int j = 0;

    while (n--) {
        cin >> no_of_elem_array;

        for (int i = 0; i < no_of_elem_array; i++) {
            cin >> arr[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < no_of_elem_array; i++) {
            sum[j] = sum[j] + arr[i];
        }
        j++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << sum[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

2

4

1 2 3 4

6

5 8 3 10 22 45

Comment: As @alan has suggested, you do not even need to store the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is n in your final loop

```
   for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
   cout<<sum[i]<<endl;
    }
```

which is become 0 in

```
         while(n--)
```

that is why it is not print anything

Answer (score 0):

That is not how one adds arrays in C++:

This is the code I propose:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec_of_ints;
    std::cout << "Enter the size of the array: ";
    unsigned size = 0;
    std::cin >> size;
    vec_of_ints.resize(size);
    for(auto& integer : vec_of_ints) {
        std::cin >> integer;
    }
    std::cout << std::accumulate(vec_of_ints.begin(), vec_of_ints.end(), 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, as @Alan Birtles has suggested, there is another (and better) alternative:

**you do not need to store the input at all**:

```
int main() {
    unsigned size = 0;
    std::cin >> size;
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int num = 0;
        std::cin >> num;
        sum += num;
    }
    std::cout << sum << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But, if we don't store the array here for sum how would we get 2 different sum for the 2 different arrays entered?

Comment: Yes, the first line of the output statement indicates that 2 arrays are there. The line after that indicates that the size of the first array is 2 and then the elements of that array in the next line.

Answer (score -1):

Two issues:

1. Your arrays are not big enough, so there will be invalid access, which is undefined behaviour.
2. Array `sum` is local variable, so the value is uninitialized (i.e. It contains arbitrary values when allocated), you need to set them to zero by yourself.

Comment: It's better to add a good solution alongside issues in the OP's code.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 I double checked with gcc version 9.3 and -std=c++17. Your statement is wrong and the value of local raw array's elements ARE uninit'ed.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Microsoft production expected. What I can say is standard never ask initialization with zero as it is not zero-overhead in running time. MSVC is notorious for the non-standard impl'.